# Spring Boot Sleuth Not Printing Trace and Span Logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In my spring 2.5.5 project, I am trying to configure sleuth-zipkin with the below dependencies.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The spring cloud version is

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

Now for logging - I am using Sl4J and logged in the statements using INFO.

When I run the application I can see my INFO level logs but I can't see the trace and spans ids printed nor can I see them in my Zipkin's server.

Any guesses what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do as the docs says:

1. Do not specify Spring Cloud dependencies (`<version>3.0.0</version>`), the BOM will define them
2. Use `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` which should add Sleuth support with log correlation and `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin` if you also want to send spans to Zipkin

Here's an example from the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-set-up-sleuth-with-brave-zipkin-http